# How can it be known what the Earths periods of eccentricity, perihelion and obliquity are when the observational data only cover at most 3,000 years?

Tags: orbital-motion, astronomy, history, solar-system, celestial-mechanics

How can it really be known what the earths periods of eccentricity, perihelion and obliquity are when the observational data only cover at most 3,000 years? What I mean is that these parameters involve cyclical change so we have no direct observational evidence that would give the turning points of these cycles or the lengths of them. Considering that they are supposed to be controlled by the tiny masses of the planets I wonder how they can possibly know. For example, the obliquity cycle is supposed to be 41,000 years but since we are in the middle of that and the obliquity has only been moving in one direction towards lesser obliquity what data could possibly pertain to the total length in degrees or in time?

I particularly wonder how they could vary from the periodicity of precession. How could the physics be such as to have the precessional wobble vary at a different rate than the obliquity?

I think that common sense would suggest that the periodicities would be the same.

Comment: *"we have no direct observational evidence"* Besides the very well validated theory most of the evidence is geo-climatic in origin, so you might actually get a better answer on [earthscience.se].

Comment: If you observe a small part of the motion with enough precision, you can reconstruct all of it. Especially if you know the forces involved.

Comment: You might just as well argue there is no experimental evidence that precession is periodic. After all, what's the difference between 26,000 and 41,000 years if you only have 3,000 years of observations? But of course there is a very well validated *model* for all of this - and we *can* observe the small differences between Newtonian and Relativistic mechanics in planetary motion (e.g. the orbit of Mercury).

Comment: Reply to Javier: How is one to know if the forces have that periodicity?

Answer (score -1):

Obviously, these can be known from the current rate if they remain uniform. They do not remain uniform so they cannot be known. If they all share the same cause, then they must have the same periodicity.